# loading times differ from localhost and remote

Tags: windows-7, time, loading

I'm running a website (made using fuel MVC) which is stored in a computer in my house, so I run it with

```
http://localhost
```

and it loads in 200ms, more or less. This time is only the time php script needs to execute, so time to transfer across the network is not taken into account. It is just execution time of the script.

However, when I access the same script out of my network (my pc at work, for example), that time measure is higuer than one second for the same page, and I don't know why it takes almost 10 times more to execute the php script when running it from an outside computer.

The computer I'm running the website on is a Windows 7 Ultimate with 3GB of RAM memory.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you profile your code? If you don't want to mess around with a PHP profiler module then you can add calls to microtime() and a logging class so you can see where it's slowing down. Also, try Chrome and Safari's Network window to see where the latency is, if that's an issue. But even so 200ms is too long for page generation - a page shouldn't take more than 50ms.

Comment: As far as I know my teammate has been dealing with the profiler, so I'll contact him and i'll post here the results in case we discover where the problem is.
Thank you.